# 3D graphics not showing everything I wanted to see

Tags: plotting, graphics3d

I am creating a plot for a geodesic dome.. Here is the code:

```
<< PolyhedronOperations`
gridFaces = 
  Cases[Normal@
    Geodesate[PolyhedronData["Icosahedron"], 1, {0, 0, 0}, 
     1.0], _Polygon, Infinity];

gridVertices = 
  Flatten[gridFaces /. Polygon[gridVertices_] -> gridVertices, 1] // 
   DeleteDuplicates;

starPositions = Normalize /@ RegionCentroid /@ gridFaces;

Table[Normal[gridFaces[[i, 1]]] , {i, Length[gridFaces]}];

gridSegments = 
  DeleteDuplicatesBy[
   Flatten[Table[
     Partition[gridFaces[[n, 1]], 2, 1, {1, 1}], {n, 
      Length[gridFaces]}], 1], Sort];

gridLinePoints = 
  Map[Normalize, 
   Table[Table[
      Subdivide[gridSegments[[n, 1, j]], gridSegments[[n, 2, j]], 
       10], {j, 1, 3}] // Transpose, {n, Length[gridSegments]}], {2}];

Grid[{{Show[{ListPointPlot3D[{starPositions}, 
      PlotStyle -> {Directive[Red, PointSize[0.01]]}, 
      BoxRatios -> Automatic, Boxed -> False, Axes -> False, 
      RotationAction -> "Clip", SphericalRegion -> True], 
     Table[Graphics3D[Line[gridLinePoints[[i]]]], {i, 1, 
       Length[gridLinePoints]}], 
     Graphics3D[Line[{{0, 0, -1.5}, {0, 0, 1.5}}]]}, 
    ImageSize -> 600]}}]

Clear[gridFaces, gridVertices, starPositions, gridLinePoints];
```

However part of the plot seems to be cut off, and it is part of 2 arcs:

[image]

Any ideas how to resolve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a very strange way to plot something. Why do you need:

```
Grid[{{Show[...]}}]
```

while you can just have `Show[...]` ? Also inside `Show` bring most general options from sub-plots into `Show` itself. Anyways your problem is with cutting off of `PlotRange`. Just expand it, for example:

```
Show[{
    ListPointPlot3D[{starPositions},
        PlotStyle->{Directive[Red,PointSize[0.01]]}],
    Table[Graphics3D[Line[gridLinePoints[[i]]]],{i,1,Length[gridLinePoints]}],
    Graphics3D[Line[{{0,0,-1.5},{0,0,1.5}}]]},
BoxRatios->Automatic,
Boxed->False,
Axes->False,
RotationAction->"Clip",
SphericalRegion->True,
PlotRange->All]
```

[image]